# How to get predefined java method Parameter names in Java 8 using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class like this

```
class Test {
    public static HashMap<String, String> aa = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void add() {
        aa.put("something", "something")
    }
}
```

I want to know how to get parameter which is pass during adding to HashMap . if there is any way to get it .

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: please edit your question, don't post code in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking how to retrieve the method put from the Hastable class

Define the method parameters' classes:

```
Class[] parametersClasses= new Class[1];
parametersClasses[0] = Object.class;
parametersClasses[1] = Object.class;
```

Retrieve the method from the class indicating the method name and it's parameters' classes:

```
Method method = aa.getClass().getMethod("put", parametersClasses);
```

Invoke the method with the proper parameters:

```
method.invoke(aa, "ABC", "test");
```